Quadratic form with Hadamard product, minimization
Let $x,y,a,b$ be the column vectors $(n,1)$ and $D_{1}(n-1,n),D_{2}(n-1,n)$
be the central difference matrices
$$
D_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
-0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5
\end{array}\right],\quad D_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & -2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1
\end{array}\right].
$$
Suppose the quadratic form
$$
\phi(x,y)=\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert _{2}^{2}+\left\Vert y-b\right\Vert _{2}^{2}+\left\Vert D_{1}x\circ D_{2}y-D_{1}y\circ D_{2}x\right\Vert _{2}^{2}
$$
that needs to minimized, $\circ$ is the Hadamard product.
Initially,
the Hadamard product can be expressed as the matrix and vector product. Let us denote
\begin{align*}
X_{1} & =diag(D_{1}x),\qquad Y_{1}=diag(D_{1}y),\qquad X_{2}=diag(D_{2}x),\qquad Y_{2}=diag(D_{2}y),\\
x_{1} & =D_{1}x,\qquad y_{1}=D_{1}y,\qquad x_{2}=D_{2}x,\qquad y_{2}=D_{2}y.
\end{align*}
The quadratic form transforms to
\begin{align*}
\phi(x,y) & =(x-a)^{T}(x-a)+(y-b)^{T}(y-b)+(X_{1}y_{2}-Y_{1}x_{2})^{T}(X_{1}y_{2}-Y_{1}x_{2}),\\
 & =(x-a)^{T}(x-a)+(y-b)^{T}(y-b)+x_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{2}x_{1}-2x_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}^{T}Y_{1}^{T}Y_{1}x_{2},\\
 & =(x-a)^{T}(x-a)+(y-b)^{T}(y-b)+y_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{1}y_{2}-2y_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{2}y_{1}+y_{1}^{T}X_{2}^{T}X_{2}y_{1}.
\end{align*}
Its extremes are given by conditions
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x} & =2(x-a)+2D_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{2}D_{1}x-4D_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{1}D_{2}x+2D_{2}^{T}Y_{1}^{T}Y_{1}D_{2}x=0,\\
\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x} & =2(y-b)+2D_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{1}D_{2}y-4D_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{2}D_{1}y+2D_{1}^{T}X_{2}^{T}X_{2}D_{1}y=0.
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
x & =(I+D_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{2}D_{1}-2D_{1}^{T}Y_{2}^{T}Y_{1}D_{2}+D_{2}^{T}Y_{1}^{T}Y_{1}D_{2})^{-1}a,\\
y & =(I+D_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{1}D_{2}-2D_{2}^{T}X_{1}^{T}X_{2}D_{1}+D_{1}^{T}X_{2}^{T}X_{2}D_{1})^{-1}b.
\end{align*}
There are three questions:

Can these formulas further be simplified or expressed in a different
(and simpler) form? For example, combining vectorization and diagonalization operations widely used with the Hadamard product computations?

Is there any analytical solution of this system?

If not, which numerical method do you recommend for solving?


Thanks for your help.
